# XCode 4 Unimotion

Tags: xcode4, accelerometer

I use Xcode 4, and I currently dont have any iDevice right now to be able to test accelerometer in my application, so I googled for a while and find util named "unimotion". read me file for Unimotion says: "A Makefile is included so all you have to do is cd to the 'unimotion' directory and type 'make'." So I tried, but terminal give me a message

> ls: /Developer/SDKs: No such file or directory cc -Wall -Os -g
>   -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/ -arch i386 -arch ppc -fconstant-cfstrings   -c -o unimotion.o unimotion.c clang: warning: not using the clang compiler for the 'powerpc' architecture unimotion.c:72:10: fatal
>   error: 'IOKit/IOKitLib.h' file not found
>
> ## include IOKit/IOKitLib.h>
>
> *1 error generated.* make[1]: *** [unimotion.o] Error 1 make: *** [sub-unimotion] Error 2

again and again.

So, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite **all** occurrences of `/Developer/SDKs/` in the 3 Makefiles (calibrate/Makefile, motion/Makefile and unimotion/Makefile) with

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/
```

that should help you. If you're using Xcode 4, you'll probably get further error also

```
llvm-gcc-4.2: error trying to exec '/usr/bin/../llvm-gcc-4.2/bin/powerpc-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2': execvp: No such file or directory
```

as the `-arch ppc` is not supported there anymore. Just delete every single occurrence of `-arch ppc` in Makefiles, and it will work.